# ERROR: When activating Transactional API in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When trying to activate the transactional API journey it keeps giving me this erorr: **Review and fix errors in this activity before activating this transactional send**.

I don't know if anyone else is getting this error and what the actual issue is, nothing tells me what the error is, the email activity does not go red like it usually does. It seems to be only on emails that I have created/modified with the same date I am trying to activate.

If anyone else has run into this problem, have you been able to locate it and fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that if you have tested your email for any possible errors! ... try to Preview and send the email `Pended application` form Email Studio to your inbox, so that there might be any can-spam errors or a personalization string error! which is causing the issue.

Comment: Check the AMPScript in your email, it is producing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error. I tested the email against the sendable data extension, so I knew that was fine. Eventually I gave up on using the interface and just used the default journey option when creating the send definition.

"options": {
"createJourney": true
}

Documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm

This way the journey is immediately active and does not give an error for the same email content. Don't use the interface to configure the transactional journey - that functionality is too recent and doesn't seem to work very well.